# passing a function vs calling a function

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

what is the difference if any of calling a function vs passing a function in c?

For instance on printf there is:

```
_doprnt(register const char *fmt, va_list *argp, void (*putc)(char), int radix){
...
while ((c = *fmt) != '\0') {
    if (c != '%') {
        (*putc)(c);
        fmt++;
        continue;
    }
```

Why do that if you can simply call it?

Comment: So that you can pass different (compatible) functions to be called by `_doprnt()`. The library function `qsort()` is an example of where this is required.

Comment: If you can simply call what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function usually referred to as a callback for to be called in the case some event occurs. Calling a function occurs..well when you call it. In your example it seems like it's taking into account some arguments before calling putc. Regardless it's probably not the best example.

Imagine a keyboard handler which triggers a callback each time a user presses a key.
You might be able to register the handle like so:

```
void registerkeyboardhandler(keyboardcallback handler){
    /*
     *create a handler
     */
}
```

Which wants a function pointer of type keyboardcallback handler, and we can define that as such:

```
typedef void (*keyboardcallback)(int keycode, int down);
```

Now registerkeyboardhandler will probably hook onto some keyboard input and whenever a user presses a key, the callback will be called and a keycode as well as if the key was down/up will be passed.

The handler could be simple

```
void keyboardcallbackhandler(int keycode, int down){
    switch(keycode){
        case 0x00:
            //do something
            switch(down){
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And we can probably call registerkeyboardhandler from main

```
int main(void){
    registerkeyboardhandler(keyboardcallbackhandler);
}
```

But essentially, function pointers are ideal for callbacks to be triggered in the case of some event to occur potentially later on.

A more practical example could be an array sorting method which allows you to dictate how you want the sorting to occur.

Consider this sort method

```
void sort(int* p,int size, sortmethod smt){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            if(smt(p[i],p[j])){
                int temp = p[i];
                p[i] = p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It takes an int array, a size as well as a callback to decide how you wish to perform the sort between two integers.
And this is my array

```
int p[] = {3,2,4,1,5,9};
```

Now if I wanted to sort from least to greatest I could make my sort callback method like so

```
int sortby(int x, int y){
    return x<y;
}
```

But if I wanted to make my array from greatest to least I could just flip the sign

```
int sortby(int x, int y){
    return x>y;
}
```

And when I call sort from main, I can use my callback to let sort know how I want the sort to be performed

```
typedef int (*sortmethod)(int x, int y);
int sortby(int x, int y){
    return x>y;
}

void sort(int* p,int size, sortmethod smt){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j){
            if(smt(p[i],p[j])){
                int temp = p[i];
                p[i] = p[j];
                p[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void){
    int p[] = {3,2,4,1,5,9};
    sort(p,sizeof(p)/sizeof(int),sortby);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p)/sizeof(int);++i){
        printf("%d\n",p[i]);
    }
}
```

The sort takes care of the algorithm while the critical step of how the sorting should be done is handled by you.